# in java null value in String

Tags: java, string, null

I get a compilation error at `prt(null)` in the following:

```
 public class Abc {

    public static void prt(String b)
    {
        System.out.println("I m static Method with String");
    }
    public static void prt(Abc n)
    {
        System.out.println("I m static Method with Object");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prt(null);

    }

}
```

but this class is fine:

```
public class Abc {

    public static void prt(String b)
    {
        System.out.println("I m static Method with String");
    }
    public static void prt(Object n)
    {
        System.out.println("I m static Method with Object");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prt(null);

    }

}
```

Please help me understand null value in String, in any class object and in Object class object.

Answer (score 2):

You should read carefully full compiler message. Its probably complains that the call prt(null) is ambiguous.
In fact you should typecast it: **prt((String)null)** or **prt((Abc)null)** to let compiler know what [parameter overloaded](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Overloading_Methods_and_Constructors) method to call.

Quote to explore:

> It will call the method whose parameter type is a subclass of the
>   parameter type of the other method. Beware! The parameter type is
>   defined by the declared type of an object, not its instantiated type.